# Windows 10 - Connect to a wireless display fails part way through - worked once and then never again

Tags: windows-10, drivers, miracast

I am trying to get a Dell laptop to connect to a Samsung TV. It worked one time and then after that (I think the same day and think very likely no updates were installed in between) I inexplicably couldn't get it to work again and haven't been able to since.

- I hit WinKey+P and choose "Connect to a wireless display" and choose the TV and it shows that it's trying to connect on both **the TV itself** (this is an important note) and the laptop but ends in the message seen below "Couldn't connect to your device".
- I tried updating the wireless card driver and the display driver via device manager and having it search for updated drivers and both are now on what it says are the most current but no luck.
- Another Windows device is still able to connect just fine.
- I also tried removing the device from Windows Settings -> Devices and adding it again there but that didn't work either.
- DxDiag's output says "Miracast: Available, with HDCP"
- The TV says it has no software updates available

Here's the message when it fails: 
[image]

Comment: What happens when you try to initiate the screen sharing from the TV instead of from Windows? On the TV's Menu > Source > Remote Access > Screen Sharing (Wireless). Does it give you the same error?

Comment: @GenTest I get the same issue when on that screen, though in case I'm missing something, it won't let me initiate it from the TV on that screen - it just tells me the instructions to initiate from the computer.

Comment: @g491 did you find a solution? having the exact same problem

Comment: @Janar It does work now, but I forget what I did - it may have been either a different Samsung TV or upgrading Windows (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to a newer release.  I'm also using a different WiFi access point but am not sure if that matters.  Good luck.